# Servlet, JSP, JavaBeans and HTML form

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, servlets

I'm working on a servlet that makes a connection to a database gets the information of one of the tables ans sends this information to a jsp file. This file will print on the brower the information table, adding radio buttons that allows us to choose one of the rows.

The servlet looks like this:

```
List<InfoBean> items = new ArrayList<InfoBean>();
if (!conexion.isClosed()){
  Statement st = (Statement) conexion.createStatement();          
  ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from lista_audio" );
  while (rs.next())
  {items.add(getRow(rs));}
  conexion.close();}
req.getSession().setAttribute("items", items);
```

In the JSP file I can print a table with the information, adding radio buttons that the user will use to choose 1 row and send the selected info to a servlet using a form I can add:

```
< form action="administ" method=get enctype=multipart/form-data>    
< table>
 < table border=\"1\">< tr>< th>Title< /th>< th>Author< /th>< th>Album< /th>< /tr>
 < c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
 < tr>< td><input type="radio" name="SongInfo" value=${item.title}>
 < td>${item.title}< /td>
 < td>${item.author}< /td>
 < td>${item.album}< /td>< /tr>
 < /c:forEach>
< /table>
```

In the field 'value' I should be able to send to the servlet the information stored in ${item.title}. When I set value = ${item.title} and title is, for example "The bodyguard", in the servlet the information I can retrieve is just "The". It looks like it sends the characters located before the first white space of the string. How could I get the whole string?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the generated HTML output (rightclick page in browser, choose View Source). Don't you miss something?

```
<input type="radio" name="SongInfo" value=The bodyguard>
```

Yes, the quotes (note the difference in highlighted color, `bodyguard` became an attribute).

So, fix it:

```
<input type="radio" name="SongInfo" value="${item.title}">
```

This way it'll be generated as follows:

```
<input type="radio" name="SongInfo" value="The bodyguard">
```

Simple fix, isn't it? :)

---

That said, your JDBC code is prone to resource leaks. You should close all the resources `Connection`, `Statement` and `ResultSet` in the finally block of the try block you've acquired them. For more hints see [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html). Also the list doesn't necessarily need to be put in the session scope. Also the HTML is syntactically invalid, but that's maybe just a copypaste error, it would otherwise not have worked.

Further on, your HTML form is declared to use the request method of `GET`, but it is also declared to use encoding type of `multipart/form-data`. This makes no utter sense. **Only** use this enctype whenever you have an `<input type="file">` and if this is the case, the request method ought to be `POST`.